# How do I make copies of a Node in Godot

Tags: c#, visual-studio, game-engine, godot

I'm new to Godot coming fresh from unity and I cant figure out how to duplicate an object/node. I've tried the duplicate function to no effect. My most recent attempts try to create child nodes with the same property as the parent. I cant seem to get anywhere, help would be appreciated. Here is my code that tries to create a child node:

```
Node copynode = new Node();

// Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
public override void _Ready()
{
    copynode = this;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        AddChild(copynode);         
    }

}
```

Also could someone tell me what the object/node/item in the scene is actually called and how to reference it? Is it a Node or a Gamedot.Object or something else? And how do I get and set its properties? I'm just really used to unity and cant figure this stuff out. The only tutorials I find are in the Godot language, and I kind of know c# already so I would prefer to program in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nodes are references**

I believe you expected `Node` to behave as a value type, but actually it is a reference. Let us over what happens:

Here you declare a variable of type `Node`, and initialize it to a new `Node`:

```
Node copynode = new Node();
```

And then here you overwrite it with the `Node` on which this script is being executed:

```
copynode = this;
```

And then you try to add the `Node` as child of itself five times:

```
AddChild(copynode);
```

Which, of course, does not work. *And you do that five times.*

Let us be glad this does not work. Because if it did, you have a `Node` that makes *five* copies of itself, which each also make *five* copies of themselves, and you can imagine how that goes. *Which is why I will not give you some code to do it.*

---

As you are aware there is a duplicate method. I suspect you expected it to add the duplicate to the scene tree. However it does not do that. Instead it returns the duplicate, and you have to add it (or do something else with it).

---

**Your questions**

> Also could someone tell me what the object/node/item in the scene is actually called and how to reference it?

I'm not sure what you mean. However, if it helps, `this` will refer to the object on which the script is executing.

---

> Is it a Node or a Gamedot.Object or something else?

The class `Godot.Node` inherits from `Godot.Object`. If you attached a script to a `Node` the class of your script must inherit form the type of the `Node`, which could be `Godot.Node` or a class that inherits from `Godot.Node`. *I hope that helps.*

> And how do I get and set its properties?

You get and set them like any C# property. Although you should be able to use the `Get` and `Set` methods too, but that is intended for dynamic code.

If what you are looking for is how to make the properties available in the inspector panel, you do that by adding the `[Export]` attribute. For example:

```
[Export]
public float Speed;
```

And it should appear in the inspector panel when the object that has the script is selected.

---

> The only tutorials I find are in the Godot language, and I kind of know c# already so I would prefer to program in that.

Most of the tutorials are in GDScript because:

- There are two Godot builds. One with C# and one without it. But both can use GDScript. Thus GDScript is useful regardless of which build you are using.
- Translating from GDScript to C# is not difficult. It is mostly the naming convention (and some edge cases, which you are probably not encounter when you are beginning). See [C# API differences to GDScript](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_differences.html).
- The way C# is used with Godot follows C# conventions. *I'd argue that it follows them closer than Unity. Although there are some rough edges when it comes to signals and async methods.*

See the video [Intro to C# in Godot 3.1: Your First Script (tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRuUHxOCYz0) by GDQuest.

I'll also recommend the underrated video [Godot C# Delegate Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FX5LEUsjRXo&t).

And hare some YouTube channels have some C# Godot content that I've found: [FinePointCGI](https://www.youtube.com/c/FinePointCGI), [BurgZerg Arcade](https://www.youtube.com/c/BurgZergArcade), [Abdullah](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClzV7jGJREjvCTzfGTrdrkQ), [BeIndie - Alan Thorn](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF1X3sTIj-pCIcR_C2wg6SQ), [Godot Academy](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMCeSdXq6d3Zghx28U7IGvw).

---

**Some advice for Unity developers arriving to Godot**

Since you are familiar with C#, go ahead and use C#.

By the way my personal recommendation is to use an external editor (such as Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code, for which there are some good plugins for Godot) instead of using the integrated one. Because - even thought C# is fully supported - C# is poorly integrated with the editor.

Also be aware it is OK to use both C# and GDScript on the same project, or Godot visual scripting, or other languages that can be added to Godot (or even C++ if you really want to). How much C# you use is up to you.

Thus, you can use each language to their strength. For example you can use C# to get some extra performance compared to GDScript, and have access to all the .NET libraries and some modern language features. And use GDScript as glue with the rest of Godot (e.g. exporting variables and connecting singals, and calling into C#).

*If you decide to combine GDScript and C# be aware the GDScript cannot properly consume C# async methods. My advice for that is to design around signals when they need to interact asynchronously.*

---

Before you ask how to use components. There are multiple ways to build a component system on top of Godot, but it does not include one. And you probably don't need them. Most of what Unity does with components is done in Godot with `Node`s instead.

Furthermore, coming from Unity, you might be expecting some distinction between "prefab", "scene" and "node". There isn't. An scene can have other scenes inside, and the scenes are nodes. And as I said, you will use nodes instead of components.

*That does not mean that everything is nodes. You absolutely can make classes that are not nodes. It can be in particular useful to make resource classes, but that is its own topic.*

Although, scenes are nodes, there is an slight distinction: a scene is a node that is serialized. Thus if you want to create a whole thing that can be instantiated multiple times, then you want to create a scene. And then you can add that scene as a node - which it is - inside of another scene. Similarly when you import model that you can place in a scene… the models are scenes.

There is an example of loading and instantiating a scene:

```
var scene = (PackedScene)ResourceLoader.Load("res://scenes/Scene.tscn");
Node scene_instance = ground.Instance();
AddChild(scene_instance);
```

*I don't know if that is what you are trying to do with your code, but I figured I'd mention it, just in case.*

---

Are you looking for an asset store. Godot does not have an asset *store*, because it sells you nothing. Instead it has an asset *library*, that you can access from the "AssetLib" button at the top of the editor. To reiterate, everything there is free, it sells you nothing. If you want some comercial assets, you will have to find them elsewhere.

*Which reminds me, the preferred format for 3D models in Godot is GLTF (which is an open standard - not a proprietary format like some others).*

---

**Godot has a way**

Some times when people go from one tool to another they try to stick to how they used the old tool. For an easy example, you don't need to make complex math to position an object relative to another, you just make it a child… But if you can't make it a child? There is `RemoteTransform` node that can do that. No code involved.

Godot is full of features hiding just below the surface, and there is value in discovering them. And if you are struggling with something, perhaps there is a Godot way. And if there isn't, it can be added.

*I'll tell you one that is particularly powerful: the `AnimationPlayer` node can animate any exported property. In fact, it can call methods. It can also start animations in other `AnimationPlayer`s.*

By the way, it goes without saying, but: for whatever code you find online, try to understand the reasoning behind it. It will save you trouble when it does not work and you have to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question it helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Untitled.png]

- The base node class is invisible (gray) so you cannot see if they were added or not. You can switch from the local to the remote tab in the scene tree while running to see only one invisible node added.
- If you change the code to `AddChild(copynode.Duplicate());` you can see it adds all 5 invisible nodes.

Comment: i love how you explain it that way